# Protect display contact number

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a classified website and in the product detail of page the contact number is show as normal text. These numbers are visible in search engine result. How to protect or how to show phone number as image to hide from SE?

Comment: Numbers simply as bitmaps or even more destructed like a reverse captcha problem? What about some code you tried, or is this in an exploratory phase? As it stands you kind of ask for a plugin or library which might lead to closing of the question here at SO. Thanks.

Comment: Numbers are saved in mysql db. I don't what to display it just like text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar to this. This will print your phone number as an image.

```
<?php
$img = imagecreate(100, 20); //dimension of image

$bg = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255); //Give white background
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0); //Gives black colour to string. Both follow format in format (image, Red, Green, Blue)
$phone = "1234567890";
imagestring($img, 6, 2, 2, $phone, $textcolor);
// imagestring ( resource $image , int $font , int $x , int $y , string $string , int $color )

// Output the image
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($img); //Outputs a png image
imagedestroy($img); //frees any memory associated with image
?>
```